# Laravel Query Builder - Complex select column error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I have 2 table like this-

**panelists**

[image]

**users**

[image]

I have a Laravel 5.1 query builder like this-

```
    $baseQuery = DB::table('panelists')
        ->join('users', 'panelists.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select(
            'users.id',
            'users.name',
            'users.email',
            'IF(enabled=1,"English Book","Other Language")   AS status'
        )
        ->where('panelists.customer_id', '=', $user_ID);
```

But it is giving me error for

```
          'IF(enabled=1,"English Book","Other Language")   AS status'
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Post exact error message

Comment: Try DB::raw for raw queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: You may use `DB::Raw` for raw queries.

```
$baseQuery = DB::table('panelists')
    ->join('users', 'panelists.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select(
        'users.id',
        'users.name',
        'users.email',
         DB::raw('IF(enabled=1,"English Book","Other Language")AS status')
    )
    ->where('panelists.customer_id', '=', $user_ID);
```